# Структура Redux Store

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Вопросы не столько о конкретно [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux), рассматривается в целом порог вхождения на flux-подобных фреймворках, но частным примером будет Redux, потому что он крут среди альтернатив.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 04.09.2015:**
Нашел отличный репозиторий c сылками по redux https://github.com/xgrommx/awesome-redux

*Начало.*

Был разработан прототип проекта с использованием kendo-ui в качестве фронтэнд-фреймворка. Проект большой, основная его суть - генерировать интерфейс на лету (в основном сложные формы или отчеты) с помощью meta-схемы с сервера (которая так же может правиться с помощью визуального редактора). kendo неплохо с этим справлялся, пока проект не перерос все возможности kendo (почти все виджеты приходилось переделывать под себя и куча других неприятностей). Было принято решение переписывать все "полностью свое" и выбор пал на react+flux, затем на redux+react.

**Основной ВОПРОС: Как правильно организовать структуру redux store для большого проекта?**

Даллее подвопросы:

***1) Примеры***

Одними todo-mvc с "вау-эффектом" не насытишься. Откуда посмотреть пример хоть чего-то маломальски сложного?

***2) Сложность поиска информации***

По запросу "redux" гугл не соображает, чего я именно хочу (мало того, там есть redux framework, который не имеет никакого отношения к делу). Что уж говорить о "redux complex application". Подскажите как гуглить?

***3) Непонятно как структурировать приложение.***

Есть основные концепты, описанные у многих авторов чудесных вещей, но это сравнимо с знанием, что у тебя есть две ноги и ты ими можешь ходить. Как? Твое дело. Понятно, что у каждого "свой стиль" разработки, но должны же быть какие-то постулаты, чтобы не натыкаться на камни, на которые сто раз наткнулись люди до тебя. Получается, оптимальные варианты сейчас находятся методом тыка. Иногда цена этого "тыка" - пара часов. Иногда пара дней.
Нет уверенности в каком месте какой кусок кода писать. Иногда количество вариантов доходит до 5 (и увеличивается по мере наращивания мяса приложения), на выбор одного из них тратится время. Иногда выбор оказывается неверным или противоречащим последующим действиям.

Да, понятно, что есть один большой redux-store в котором хранятся данные. Но все ли данные должны храниться там? Или все же должны быть какие-то локальные состояния компонентов, к примеру? Или локальные состояния должны задаваться в "умных" компонентах и передавать "тупым"?
Как повлияет на производительность, если в этот redux-store (созданный immutable, например) засовывать вообще все данные состояний компонентов? Как должна выглядеть в таком случае структура этого store в оптимальном варианте?

Ведь если **не** хранить визуальные данные компонентов в redux-store, то полноценного time-traveling не получится.

Оффтоп:
Товарищи, как вы получаете знание и уверенность в том, что делаете? Ведь новые техники (es6)/технологии(react)/архитектуры(flux) появляются с каждым днем как грибы (особенно в web мире), а голова не резиновая

Comment: Важнее, чтобы просто работало, чем чтобы работало идеально, но позже на два года. А вопрос стоит закрыть как неконкретный.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв, я понимаю некорректность вопроса, но негде написать было. Думаете стоит разбить на несколько конкретных? 
Не по теме: Не подскажите литературу по правильной организации подобных проектов?

Comment: Думаю, такой вопрос можно на toster.ru . Сам задаюсь такими вопросами - поучаствую  в обсуждении

Comment: @Sergiks Вынужден уже не согласиться с Вашей точкой зрения, смотря на все это из будущего. Относительно сложно сделать чтобы "просто" работало. Время на обдумывание, что и как должно работать и на обдумывание структуры следует потратить стоит столько, сколько требуется. Оно окупается с лихвой в Redux-driven приложениях. Monkey кодинг тут не прощается. Я раньше сам был фанатом подхода "Сначала пускай заработает, а там разберемся". Работать то оно может, но так чтоб расширяемо и поддерживаемо - едва ли неодумав выйдет

Это новое веб-программирование. Думать "по-старому" лично у меня не вышло

Comment: Спасибо автору за вопрос, подняты и хорошо описаны важные проблемы. Жаль, что вопрос закрыли? Есть ли ссылки на разбитые на части вопросы.

Comment: Здесь я задал один из подвопросов и на него ответил разработчик Redux - Dan Abramov
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053831/redux-data-structuring